# Django on apache io error

Tags: python, django, apache, permissions, file-permissions

My day-old django project is already running on Apache 2. This is the general structure:

```
root/apps/django/django_projects/Project
├── autocache
│   ├── cache.py
│   └── cache.txt
├── conf
├── manage.py
├── Project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── ...
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── ...
```

When `myapp` is shown, I simply show the contents of `cache.txt`. This is what I have to do that:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
import os

def index(request):
    cache_path = os.path.join(settings.CACHE_DIR, 'cache.txt')
    with open(cache_path, 'r') as cache:
        return HttpResponse(cache.read())
    return "Could not open file"
```

The problem is that an exception is being thrown:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://myip/Project/subwayapp/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/apps/django/django_projects/Project/autocache/cache.txt'
Exception Location: /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/myapp/views.py in index, line 8
Python Executable:  /opt/bitnami/python/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.13
```

However, this is the output of `ls -l` for `cache.txt`:

```
-rwxrwxr-- 1 root root  17 Oct  8 16:06 cache.txt
```

As I understand it, this means that

1. It is a file
2. The owner can read, write, and execute it
3. The group can read, write, and execute it
4. **Everybody can read it**
5. The owner of it is `root`
6. The group of it is `root`
7. It was last modified on 10/8/17 at 16:06
8. It is called `cache.txt`

It seems to be that *everybody* should be able to read `cache.txt`, however I am getting this Permission Denied IOError. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: can you try to open the file from shell? will it be the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem or not, but I have seen issues where a parent directory is not marked readable and executable and that prevented a server from being able to access it. Try `chmod +x $PROJECT_ROOT/autocache`

Comment: What about `chown` the directory (and files) to the `www-data` user?